# Couchbase CLI refusing connection

Tags: couchbase

I'm trying to use couchbase's command line backup and restore commands (e.g., cbbackup and cbrestore) and when I type the following command:

```
cbbackup http://127.0.0.1:8891 ~/couch_backup -u [username] -p [password]
```

I consistently get a `[Errno 61] Connection refused` error.

I have validated that the username and password I'm using are the same as what I use to log into the web interface successfully. Should these two username/password combinations be the same? Can anyone think of any other reason why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couchbase is usually listen on `8091` port, not `8891`. So if you didn't change port manually try:

```
cbbackup http://127.0.0.1:8091 ~/couch_backup -u [username] -p [password]
```

Comment: Oh my god. You're right! I can't find my house keys when I'm going out and apparently I can't spot a typo on the port number either. :)  Thanks though, you're a lifesaver.